# How to return largest value of the selected row?

Tags: mysql, select, row

I'm trying to select latest date in row (not in column)

It must be 'articles_date_added' or 'articles_last_modified' in table like that

```
Id | ... | ... | articles_date_added | articles_last_modified | ...
```

My real query looks like:

```
select 
  a.articles_id, a.authors_id, a.articles_date_added,
  a.articles_last_modified,
  IF(a.articles_last_modified >= a.articles_date_added,
     a.articles_last_modified,
     a.articles_date_added) as latestdate,
  ad.articles_viewed,
  ad.articles_name, ad.articles_head_desc_tag,
  COUNT(vh.articles_id) as total_votes,
  SUM(v.vote_value)/COUNT(v.vote_value) AS vote_avg,
  au.authors_name, td.topics_name, a2t.topics_id 
from
  " . TABLE_ARTICLES . " a
  left join " . TABLE_AUTHORS . " au using(authors_id)
  left join VOTE_HISTORY vh using (articles_id)
  left join VOTE v using (vote_id),
  " . TABLE_ARTICLES_DESCRIPTION . " ad,
  " . TABLE_ARTICLES_TO_TOPICS . " a2t
  left join " . TABLE_TOPICS_DESCRIPTION . " td using(topics_id)
where 
  (a.articles_date_available IS NULL or
  to_days(a.articles_date_available) <= to_days(now())) and
  a.articles_status = '1' and a.articles_id = a2t.articles_id and
  ad.articles_id = a2t.articles_id and
  ad.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'
  and td.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'
  and a2t.topics_id = '" . (int)$current_topic_id . "' and
  au.authors_id = '" . (int)$_GET['filter_id'] . "' 
GROUP BY a.articles_id 
ORDER BY latestdate desc
```

As you can see to select it I use

```
IF(a.articles_last_modified >= a.articles_date_added,
a.articles_last_modified, a.articles_date_added) as latestdate
```

but it returms 1054 - Unknown column 'latestdate' in 'order clause

Why?

I'm on MySql 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Since adding is a modification, it'd be a good idea if your a.articles_last_modified would contain the same date as a.articles_date_added upon inserting a row.

```
UPDATE `articles`
SET `articles_last_modified` = `articles_date_added`
WHERE `articles_last_modified` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

ALTER TABLE `articles`
CHANGE COLUMN `articles_last_modified` `articles_last_modified` 
TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This way you won't need this condition in where clausule

Comment: Happy to report the prob is sorted. Spent a few hours))) The trick is in syntax of ORDER BY 'latestdate' desc. Only working with ' '